# Add Company Letter head to sharepoint 2013 workflow generated emails

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, workflow, email

I'm working on a purchase order form and it is required to have a letter head which consist of a .png logo. I have connected a SharePoint list to an automatically generated email within a workflow. As far as I can tell there is no simple way to add an image to an email from SharePoint 2013 workflow. If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Ben,

Not sure about Out of the Box Workflows, but you can create custom SharePoint Designer Workflow and edit the emails as shown in following:

[Creating HTML Emails with SPD Workflows](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/creating-html-emails-with-spd-workflows.aspx)
[How to create rich HTML email message in Sharepoint Designer 2010 workflow ?](http://sharepointjim.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/how-to-create-rich-html-email-message-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/)
[How do I embed a graphic into a SharePoint Designer workflow?](http://thomasthetestengine.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-do-i-embed-graphic-into-sharepoint.html)

PS: All articles are for 2010, but I guess it should be same for 2013!